# Calling a function from another class in theos(logos) Jailbreak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, theos, logos

I'm trying to run a function from another Class in another Class.

I want to call `-(void)updateClock` from the Class `SBAwayView`

Ive tried `[[%c(SBAwayDateView) sharedInstance] updateClock];`

Ive also tried `[%c(SBAwayDateView) updateClock];`
but I can't get it to work. (the SpringBoard crashes and I'm in safemode)

Below is the `SBAwayDateView` Class

```
    %hook SBAwayDateView
    -(void)updateClock
    {
    //do some stuff

   //run %orig;
      %orig;
    }
    %end
```

How can I run `-(void)updateClock` in `SBAwayView` Class below?

```
    %hook SBAwayView
    -(void)updateInterface
    {
    //do some stuff

    //How can I run -(void)updateClock here?

   //run %orig;
      %orig;
    }
    %end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does [%c(SBAwayView) sharedInstance] return a valid instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SBAwayDateView` doesn't have `sharedInstance` nor `updateClock` **class** methods.

In cases when you are working with class that is not a singleton you need to either find valid instance of this class in some other class - it might contain it in instance variable or return from some method. Or you can hook `init` method and save somewhere instances yourself. Depends on what you want to do.

In your case `SBAwayView` has instance variable `SBAwayDateView *_dateHeaderView` - problem solved

```
%hook SBAwayView
-(void)updateInterface
{
    //do some stuff

    SBAwayDateView* dateView = MSHookIvar<SBAwayDateView*>(self, "_dateHeaderView");
    [dateView updateClock];

    //run %orig;
    %orig;
}
%end
```

Comment: Thank you! It does have the updateClock method when I look at the headers. @creker

Comment: I was talking about class methods ('+' methods). SBAwayDateView does have updateClock instance method ('-' methods).